# Unable to run Jboss AS 7.1.3 with JDK 1.8

Tags: java, jboss, java-8, jboss7.x, jdk6

We have an existing JSF application on Jboss 7.1.3 and Jdk 1.6. We are trying to upgrade it to jdk 1.8 but server does not start.

Following is the log that is generated:

```
12:49:03,282 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
12:49:03,657 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:49:03,704 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" starting
12:49:03,704 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\SIKAND~1.AHM\AppData\Local\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6u121\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6u121\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\sikander.ahmed\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;.
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_91-b14
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_91
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.91-b14
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.home.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final
    jboss.host.name = pitt-l-sikander
    jboss.messaging.ServerPeerID = 82
    jboss.modules.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = pitt-l-sikander
    jboss.qualified.host.name = pitt-l-sikander
    jboss.server.base.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.default.config = standalone-full.xml
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = pitt-l-sikander
    jboss.server.temp.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\modules
    org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING = UTF-8
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER = TestServer
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\log\boot.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.quartz.properties = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone/configuration/quartz.properties
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows 8.1
    os.version = 6.3
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = standalone.bat
    stat.deploy.db.host = 52.7.53.54
    stat.deploy.db.instance = STATDB_UAT_NEW
    stat.deploy.db.port = 1433
    stat.deploy.db.pwd = ST@t5ql$vc
    stat.deploy.db.user = STATSQLSVC
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.quartz.properties=E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone/configuration/quartz.properties -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER=TestServer -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=UTF-8
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = 
    sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval = 3600000
    sun.stderr.encoding = cp437
    sun.stdout.encoding = cp437
    user.country = US
    user.dir = E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\bin
    user.home = C:\Users\sikander.ahmed
    user.language = en
    user.name = sikander.ahmed
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = America/New_York
    user.variant = 
12:49:03,704 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone-full-ha.xml -Dstat.deploy.db.host=52.7.53.54 -Dstat.deploy.db.port=1433 -Dstat.deploy.db.user=STATSQLSVC -Dstat.deploy.db.pwd=ST@t5ql$vc -Dstat.deploy.db.instance=STATDB_UAT_NEW -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=82 -Dorg.quartz.properties=standalone/configuration/quartz.properties -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone\log\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:E:\atClose\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

What needs to be done so we can run it on jdk 1.8?

Comment: This has been asked several times on here and other forums. JBoss AS 7 does not work with Java 8 https://developer.jboss.org/message/926279#926279.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JDK 8 then I will recommend to go with wildfly. If you want to use JBoss 7 with JDK 8 then go with JBossAS 7.4/JBossEAP 6.4.